# How to work with regex to check a content of String

Tags: java, regex, string

i need to check if a string have in your content minimum two commas and maximum three commas and one hyphen. I'm trying to make a regex to validate this String.
Ex:

```
String address = "Av. Rocio, 45, - Center";
String regex = "//,{2,3}|-{1}";
boolean isValid = address.matches(regex);
```

But don't working, always return false, what i did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to use`String regex = ".*(//,{2,3}|-).*";`?

Comment: What is the purpose of `//` in your regex? Did you perhaps want to escape `,`? If that so, then escaping character is ``\`` which in String literal has to be written as ``\\``. But since `,` is not special character in regex (at least outside of `{x,y}` you don't need to escape it.

Comment: Your regex would match two slashes followed by two or three consecutive commas ( `"//,,"` or `"//,,,"`), or a single dash. I don't think that's what you meant as there are no slashes and no consecutive commas in your string. Read a [regex tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and remember that slashes `/` and backslashes `\​` are two different things.

Comment: ""Validate if it has 2 or 3 commas""?? Uhm, rather validate if it has 2 (it doesn't matter if there's one more when validating). or do you mean it can't have 4? It needs clarification.

Comment: Hello, minimum is 2 commas and the maximum is 3. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, so i tried to use the slash for catching commas and the hyphen in the middle of String, but was a failed attempt by me, i still need to read many regex tutorials.
By the way. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a string that has ONLY 2 or 3 commas and not more than 1 hyphen, use:

```
String regex = "(?s)^(?=([^,]*,){2,3}[^,]*$)(?=[^-]*-[^-]*$).*";
```

The `matches` method requires a full string match, thus, we need to add `.*`.

Note that `{1}` limiting quantifier is redundant, as `-` will match exactly 1 hyphen.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/tr2oXD).

The regex (where `.` matches a newline due to `(?s)` inline dotall modifier) matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=([^,]*,){2,3}[^,]*$)` - Lookahead that checks the presence of 2 or 3 commas
- `(?=[^-]*-[^-]*$)` - lookahead that requires only 1 hyphen to be in the string
- `.*` - match all the string if the 2 conditions above are satisfied.

Comment: @Mariano: Yes, many a thank! I spent much time editing, and that was really a redundant subpattern.

Comment: Another site that helps is debuggex, it helps visualize and show the regex and evaluation